# Mapbox performance updating on scroll

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on an app that uses Mapbox to display a route and allows the users to navigate it by scrolling up and down the page.

I'm using some techniques similar to what is shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/). Like directly updating the source with new coordinates and moving the map on each iteration (I use `flyTo` instead of `panTo` because I also update the zoom/bearing)

When analyzing Mapbox's example using the performance tab of Chrome DevTools, their framerate looks great. But, when doing the same in my app, it's much less consistent and some frames take 50 to 100ms.

[Performance tab example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSpge.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, there are some `requestAnimationFrame` calls that are not triggered by my code and that take a lot of time to execute.

I have limited experience working with animations or Js performance improvements. I've been looking around for a while and tried a lot of different options.

The code is very similar to the following:

```
const app = new App();

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  app.onScroll();
});


class App {

  [...]

  onScroll() {
    this.latestScroll = window.pageYOffset;

    if(!this.ticking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroll.bind(this));
      this.ticking = true;
    }
  }

  updateScroll() {
    this.ticking = false;

    [...]

    if (this.shouldUpdate()) {
      this.drawPath(path);
      this.moveCamera(position, bearing, zoom);
    }
  }

  drawPath(path) {
    const geojson = {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: path
      }
    };

    this.map.getSource('route').setData(geojson);
  }

  moveCamera(position, bearing, zoom) {
    this.map.flyTo({
      center: position,
      bearing,
      zoom,
      animate: false,
    });
  }
}
```